# How to find characters ahead of word using re?

Tags: python, regex

So I would like to obtain the number that is ahead of the word pies. How would I do this?

```
import re
string='latin 1,394 pies'
m = re.search('', string)
print(m.group(0))
#want 1,394
```

Comment: Are you using Python?  Please tag with the appropriate language.

Comment: I'd suggest an excellent regex testing site, that not only you could rapidly test your regex but also has detail explanation why certain result is shown based on your regex, great for learning regex. 
https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
In [137]: import re
     ...: string='latin 1,394 pies'
     ...: m = re.search(r'([\d,]+) pies', string)
     ...: print(m.group(1))
     ...: 
1,394



([\d,]+) pies
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Regex101 Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/dT8gE8/1)